# What does the feedback capacitor do in Right-Leg-Driver?

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier, biopotential, integrator

It so happens I have seen some people mention about connect a feedback capacitor across the opamp for RLD would improve something better.

[image]

Can someone capable to explain about the use of the capacitor?

Comment: Right-leg-driver? What does that mean? Which capacitor? Which part of the circuit?

Comment: @Andyaka It is an ECG AFE and it is used to make reference potential on your right leg with skin electrode.

Comment: I am amazed at how there's always someone so deeply prepared on a so tiny field of knowledge on this site @venny

Comment: @venny thanks but I wanted the OP to include that in his question - it's important that questions are understandable by more folks if that's possible.

Comment: What's the application of this circuit and are you asking what is the purpose of the 1000p capacitor?

Comment: Yupz. I forgot to update the what is RLD in my question.

Comment: i jz simply put some magic value

Comment: Gentlemen - did you realize the feedback on the NON-INVERTING terminal?

Comment: Good call, @LvW --  this is NOT a functional circuit

Answer (score 1):

The capacitor in feedback loop turns the amplifier into a lossy integrating amplifier with corner frequency of \$\frac{1}{2\pi R_{18} C}\cong 400\, \mathrm{Hz}\$.

Comment: That's right. I'd call it a low-pass amplifier, its gain is 39 for signals below 400Hz. Other than limiting the amplifier's bandwidth, the capacitor also improves its stability. I think the method is called dominant-pole frequency compensation.

Comment: I rather would say that the gainwould be "-1" in case of NEGATIVE feedback.